# Testing a BehaviorSubject throws no access type error

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test a behaviorSubject, but keep getting:

```
Error: <spyOnProperty> : Property myBehaviorSubject$ does not have access type get
```

this is how I declare my behaviorSubject in my myService:

```
myBehaviorSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<Array<ObjectA>>([{name: 'name1'}]);
```

and my test:

```
describe(`myMethod`, () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      myServiceMock = {
        myBehaviorSubject$: new BehaviorSubject<Array<ObjectA>>(null)
      };
      spyOnProperty(myServiceMock, 'myBehaviorSubject$', 'get').and.returnValue(observableOf([{name: 'name1'}] as Array<ObjectA>));
    });

    it('should access behaviorSubject', () => {
      myServiceMock.myBehaviorSubject$.subscribe( result => {
        //expect;
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are mocking the return value of the property access implies that you are not actually using that property directly at all. Instead of what you are doing, I'd recommend creating the spy directly, like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  myServiceMock = {
    myBehaviorSubject$: jasmine.createSpy('myBehaviorSubject$')
      .and.returnValue(observableOf([{name: 'name1'}] as Array<ObjectA>))
  };
});
```

This has the exact same effect as above, but it doesn't create a new instance of `BehaviorSubject`, which doesn't seem to be used.